# response alert displays undefined alert

Tags: javascript, php, axios

```js
axios.post(url, formData, {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
    }
  })
  .then(function(res) {
    if (res.data.success === true) {
      alert("Successfully enrolled.\nPress ok to go back");
    } else {
      alert(res.data.message);
    }
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    alert("error");
  })
```

I want to alert if $bal is lessthan 2500

```
$response = array();
if($bal>=2500){
$response['success'] = true;
$response['message'] = 'All ok';
}
else{
  $response['success'] = false;
  $response['message'] = 'insufficient balance';
}
echo json_encode($response);
```

but it alerts undefined, i am still newbie i am confused what wrong/error is in here.

Comment: Just start by changing `if (res.data.success === true) {` to `console.log(res);` and see what the format is of the return. I expect you want `if (res.success)`

Comment: your `if($bal>=2500)` should be `if($bal <=2500)` if you intend to check for `less than`.